# Cannot read property 'STRING' of undefined Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Thanks in advance, I am new to Node.js and While running the below code it shows " Cannot read property 'STRING' of undefined" error.

```
module.exports=(sequelize, Sequelize)=> {

    
const User=sequelize.define("users",{

    username: {

        type:Sequelize.STRING    
    
    },

    email: {

        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {

        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }

})
return User;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the file where you require this file ? The error is explicit, you don't pass the second argument...

Answer (score 0):

your code fix

```
// is user.js
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    return sequelize.define("users", {
        username: {
            type:Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
    });
}
```

What I modified is to add , to the last column.

my index.js file

```
// db setting user.js import
require('./user')(sequelize, Sequelize);
```

Please tell me exactly where the error occurred.

Comment: The problem is in this line type:Sequelize.STRING

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in type you should have something like this.

```
type: DataTypes.INTEGER
```

And dont forget ot import DataTypes.

```
const { DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to define type with `DataType` like this

```
 type: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
```